# Search method joing multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq, search, entity-framework-core

I need help with a search method for searching the tables for a matching text.
This works, except that the join needs to be LEFT OUTER JOIN otherwise I dont get any results if the pageId is missing in any of the tables.

This solution takes to long time to run, I would appreciate if someone can help me out with a better solution to handle this task.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Search(string query)
    {

        var temp = await (from page in _context.Pages
                          join pageLocation in _context.PageLocations on page.Id equals pageLocation.PageId
                          join location in _context.Locations on pageLocation.LocationId equals location.Id
                          join pageSpecialty in _context.PageSpecialties on page.Id equals pageSpecialty.PageId
                          join specialty in _context.Specialties on pageSpecialty.SpecialtyId equals specialty.Id

                          where
                              page.Name.ToLower().Contains(query)
                              || location.Name.ToLower().Contains(query)
                              || specialty.Name.ToLower().Contains(query)
                          select new Result
                          {
                              PageId = page.Id,
                              Name = page.Name,
                              Presentation = page.Presentation,
                              Rating = page.Rating
                          }).ToListAsync();

        var results = new List<Result>();

        foreach (var t in temp)
        {
            if (!results.Exists(p => p.PageId == t.PageId))
            {
                t.Locations = GetLocations(t.PageId);
                t.Specialties = GetSpecialties(t.PageId);
                results.Add(t);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you join? Aren't there navigation properties like `Page.PageLocations`?

Comment: @GertArnold No, I its just a plain poco object without navigation properties. Do you mean I dont have to do joins if I have navigation properties ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. It's highly recommended. If you have them it's easier to use `Any` for most of your predicates.

Comment: @GertArnold Ok, can you give me an example of how the method should look like when using navigation properties and any ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Using navigation properties, the query could look like:

```
var temp = await (from page in _context.Pages
                  where Name.Contains(query)
                     || page.PageLocation.Any(pl => pl.Location.Name.Contains(query))
                     || page.PageSpecialties.Any(pl => pl.Specialty.Name.Contains(query))
                 select new Result
                  {
                      PageId = page.Id,
                      Name = page.Name,
                      Presentation = page.Presentation,
                      Rating = page.Rating,
                      Locations = page.PageLocation.Select(pl => pl.Location),
                      Specialties = page.PageSpecialties.Select(pl => pl.Specialty)
                  }).ToListAsync();
```

This has several benefits:

1. By the absence of joins, The query returns unique `Result` objects right away, so you don't need to deduplicate them afterwards.
2. The locations and specialties are loaded in the same query instead of two queries per `Result` (aka *n+1 problem*).
3. (Likely) `ToLower` is removed because the search is probably not case sensitive anyway. The query is executed as SQL and most of the times, SQL databases have case-insensitive collations. Removing `ToLower` makes the query [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) again.

Comment: I cant get this to work, the way you have written the method. Name does not exist in the current context. Did you mean "page.Name.Contains(query)"?

Comment: Please add the `Page` class as you've got it now (including navigation properties) to your question.